# What do you call the process of reducing inflammation or the state that inflammation has been cured?

Tags: word-choice

At First I was searching the  antonyms for inflammation, concerning that one of  the antonyms for the word  "inflate" is "deflate" , but now  I don't think this is the correct way,I am unable to find the word please help me out.

Comment: One good resource is a [reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=reducing+inflammation&ls=a&loc=2osdf). *Antiphlogistic* is quite a nice word!

Comment: A drug which reduces inflammation is an 'anti-inflammatory'.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "antonym"? For most purposes, the "opposite" of, say, ***sunburned** skin* would simply be ***normal** skin*. Are you trying to describe a "**normal**, uninflamed" condition (that may always have been so), the specific condition of being ***cured** of inflamation*, or perhaps an extreme pathological condition of ***withered, shrunken** tissue*?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like *healing* should be the "opposite" of *inflammation.* However, as you have probably read, the process of inflammation is technically a part of the process of healing (even though inflammation is often the cause of a patient's pain and other problems).

In medical circles, experts speak of the *abatement* or *resolution* of inflammation.

*Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary, 31st Edition* has these entries for these terms:

> ***Abatement:*** A decrease in the severity of a pain or a symptom.
>
> ***Resolution:*** 1. The subsidence of a pathologic state, as the subsidence of an inflammation, or the softening and disappearance of a swelling.

Answer (score -1):

If a condition has ceased to manifest symptoms, it can be said to be *[quiescent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quiescent)*

> Being quiet, still, or at rest; inactive.

*The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary*

Comment: To me, "*quiescient*" lacks the connotation of "*cured*". If my physician told my my condition was "*quiescent*", I'd understand him to mean the symptoms are not currently presenting, but the underlying cause still persisted, and illness could recur at any time.

Comment: Suppose you were testing some new (not-likely-to-be-successful) chemical to include in lipstick? And for the clinical trials you used it on 50 pigs, with another 50 pigs in a "control group" that *didn't* get the treatment. If all the lipsticked pigs developed severe inflamation, but none of the control group, would you say their lips were "quiescent"? As Dan implies, I think there has to have been something that was *previously* inflamed/causing inflamation before it can be described as quiescent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't like it enough to argue for. It was all that came to mind at the time.

Comment: Well, I guess it's better than ***deflammation***, if OP had been leaning that way!

Answer (score -1):

Updating this answer:

I first heard of the term 'homeostasis' in a talk given by Dr. Deepak Chopra at MIT. He tried to define good health and 'homeostasis' as per him was one of the factors in maintaining good health.
He mentioned that term in reference to inflammation.

Link to the talk:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHmnPVApfFE

Here is the formal definition of the term:

'homeostasis'
/ˌhɒmɪə(ʊ)ˈsteɪsɪs,ˌhəʊmɪə(ʊ)ˈsteɪsɪs/

noun

the tendency towards a relatively stable equilibrium between interdependent elements, especially as maintained by physiological processes

Comment: Whilst a correct definition, some people's normal equilibrium involves continuing inflammation, so the word doesn't seem to fit to me.

Comment: This answer would be much improved by a reference for the definition, and an explanation of why this word fits the situation described in the original question.

Comment: Updated my answer.